# How to profile back-end PHP function/method performance?

Tags: php, performance, profiling

I am seeking a way to profile PHP.

**Example Scenario**

I submit an AJAX request to load an HTML Select box.  It takes on the order of 300-400 milliseconds (my human estimation) for AJAX turnaround to complete.   That was too long.  I have created a simple PHP script just for that one AJAX request and the turn-around was imperceptible.

Just poking around I have concluded that my application's startup sequence is to blame (AJAX request goes through application startup such as security, database, user authentication, etc).  I want to optimize it but I can't without more information on performance.  There could be some one/two methods that are to blame and I wish to know what those are.

How?